# How to interpret 14 CFR Part 61 Requirements 61.129 on instrument training time?

Tags: faa-regulations

For part (3)

> (i) - Ten hours of instrument training using a view-limiting device including attitude instrument flying, partial panel skills, recovery from unusual flight attitudes, and intercepting and tracking navigational systems. Five hours of the 10 hours required on instrument training must be in a single engine airplane;

Can this time be previous instrument time, or does it have to be specific to the commercial certificate?

Same thing with the night take off and landings at a towered airport.

> (4)(ii) 5 hours in night VFR conditions with 10 takeoffs and 10 landings (with each landing involving a flight in the traffic pattern) at an airport with an operating control tower.

Comment: Your first question has already been answered [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/18869/62)

Answer (score 1):

The **experience** requirement for a commercial rating need not be acquired during training for a commercial rating.